# Deploy database project to SQL Server 2008 Express

Tags: sql-server, deployment, sql-server-express, database-project

I am running SQL Server 2008 Express, version 10.0.2531.0, SP1 (64-bit) in Windows 7

I am trying to deploy a database project to this instance (using Visual Studio 2010) but I keep getting this error message

> Unable to proceed with DAC operations on the target instance because it does not support DACs. Specify another instance, or upgrade
>   to a version that supports DACs

Is there a solution that besides upgrading to another version of SQL Server, I really need to stay with an Express version. Maybe I am just missing something

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dacpacks as a mechanism to deploy database solutions were introduced in SQL Server 2008 **R2** - of which an Express edition also exists.

See: [DACPAC is a reason to upgrade to SQL Server 2008 R2](https://web.archive.org/web/20110521011536/http://infinitecodex.com/post/2010/12/09/DACPAC-is-a-reason-to-upgrade-to-SQL-Server-2008-R2.aspx)

You'll need to use that version (v10.**50**.*) to make use of DAC packs. You can download [SQL Server 2008 R2 Express](https://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx) from Microsoft for free.